# In memory file system for VS Code extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm looking to provide an in memory file system for a workspace sandbox/playground in my VS Code extension. I.e, it will load some example files into the workspace to play around with and throw away, rather than being backed via the disk or a GitHub repo, etc.

There is a VS Code sample that shows how to do this at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/main/fsprovider-sample/src/extension.ts#L11 , which registers the 'memfs' scheme.

Looking at the VS Code repo itself however, I can see it can launch with a 'playground' that uses the https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-web-playground/blob/main/src/memfs.ts extension which provides a 'memfs' scheme (see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/scripts/code-web.js#L67).

There is also code in the built-in TypeScript language service that provides an implementation which again appears to be registered as 'memfs' https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/extensions/typescript-language-features/src/filesystems/memFs.ts

And other extensions, e.g. the theme tester (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-theme-tester/blob/main/src/playground.ts#L15) register an in memory file system with a similar implementation (but this time with a different scheme).

Are extensions expected to vendor in this same code repeatedly to provide their own in memory file system? Is it not an issue if multiple extensions register the same scheme? Does VS Code not provide an implementation in the box if this is a common requirement?

I do notice VS Code has an InMemoryFileSystemProvider implementation (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/platform/files/common/inMemoryFilesystemProvider.ts#L55) and an 'inmemory' scheme (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/base/common/network.ts#L16), but I don't see this being used by extensions, so this doesn't appear to be for general usage.

Appreciate any guidance on the 'correct' approach here for providing an in-memory virtual file system.

Comment: All extensions are running in their own processes, so such implementations (whether and how to cache things in memory) are naturally decided by the extension authors I think. If you want more discussions, you can engage VS Code team via GitHub, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues

Comment: @LexLi the issue ticket space is not the right place to go for extension authoring questions/discussion. read the vscode-extensions tag wiki.

Comment: @starball Maybe take a look at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues?q=is:open+is:issue+label:extensions-development?

Comment: @LexLi look at what? I just see feature requests and bug reports. not discussion and Q&A.